# PHP: Getting MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS to work

Tags: php, mysqli

I can connect to my database with mysqli.  But when I add the MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS flag it does not connect.

I'm using PHP 7.0.10, MySQL 5.7.14, and a WAMP installation on Windows 8.1.

I've been using:

```
$db=mysqli_connect($sHost, $sUsername, $sPassword, $sDatabase, MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
```

I get the following connection error

> Debugging errno: 2002
>   Debugging error: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: If MySQL is on the same server as PHP why would you want to add overhead? What's in the PHP log?

Comment: For the production version, MySQL is not on the same server. But for my development version I am using a localhost connection.

Comment: It looks like PHP is telling you that your mysql server rejected the connection so the next place to look would be in the mysql error log.

Comment: I think you need to be using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php possibly.

Comment: The mysql error log has nothing that relates to this.  Last errors are from yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->real_connect($sHost, $sUsername, $sPassword, $sDatabase, 0, '',  MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
```

This also works:

```
global $db; 
$db=new mysqli($sHost, $sUsername, $sPassword, $sDatabase, 0, '', MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
```

Comment: example 2 can not work, mysqli expects 6 parameters at most, not 7...

Comment: bodomalo is right: public mysqli::__construct (string $host, string $username, string $passwd, string $dbname = "", int $port, string $socket)